# How to activate Windows XP that is OEM version after Physical to Virtual migration?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware

Dell Optiplex box, used the VMWare p2v tool to migrate to VM

I can't imagine that I am the first person to ever virtualize an OEM copy of windows, so there should be a solution?

Got the VM to boot and all that (was a bit of a hassle, actually), but now Windows insists on activation.

I tried one of the XP keys I have laying around. Then used a key finder tool to pull the key off the live machine.

I go through the whole phone dial in process, give it the system ID, and either:

- They give me back an id that is not accepted by the activation screen
  or
- They do not give me a key, saying my product id cannot be found

I can boot from the XP CD to the recovery console, if that is helpful.

To note:
- I have spoken with humans in the activation line and have gotten nowhere so far
- We have lots of XP licenses, over the counter, etc. 
- This is a production system that is days of work to recreate. We need to virtualize it.

One possible path forward would be to strip the OEM version on the source system, then do P2V. Is there a known way to do this?

Comment: You can't use an OEM license in a virtual machine.  You can use an unused license of course.

Comment: @Ramhound if you use the vm only on the hardware it would not violate the OEM EULA. "*The term "COMPUTER" as used herein shall mean the HARDWARE, if the HARDWARE is a single
computer system, or shall mean the computer system with which the HARDWARE operates, if the
HARDWARE is a computer system component.*" So as long as the VM remains on the same `HARDWARE` it is still technically the same `COMPUTER`

Comment: I suppose but the virtual hardware normally is treated as its own desperate existence.  If phone activation fails I stand by my comment.  You can talk to a human during the phone activation process I would do that.

Comment: @Ramhound OP updated

Comment: Well if Microsoft cant help not sure what we can do they can force an activation if they wanted.  Have you tried another virtualization solution?  What is the host OS?

Comment: @Ramhound OP updated again! (new second line)

Comment: @Ramhound  FYI, we found a solution. See answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an answer. After all the hours of digging, it is almost embarrassing.

The solution?  When prompted for an activation key, use a DIFFERENT Dell OEM activation key.

That is it.

Dig around on some old PC, find the key, use it.

Worked for us for two or three migrations of this kind.

Once virtualized, we have moved the vm around, ESX to workstation and back, and are not re prompted.